# Linearize non-linear constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I have a problem which may be defined as:

$$\max 5 x_{11} + 6 x_{12} + 2 x_{21} + 3 x_{22} \\
x_{ij}\in \{0,1\} \\
x_{11} + x_{12} = 1 \\
x_{21} + x_{22} = 1 \\
t_1,t_2 \text { integer}  \\
(t_1 - t_2) x_1 x_2 \ge 0$$

I want to check $t_1-t_2 \ge 0$ only if $x_{11} = x_{21} = 1$.

How can I linearize this constraint? Or is it possible to linearize it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "binary"?

Comment: He means $x_{ij}\in \{0,1\}$

Comment: Can you please clarify the domain of your variables. We are assuming the "binary" means 0 or 1. Does that mean $t$ is only integers as well?

Comment: Thank you,
Yes binary means they are either 0 or 1. $x_{ij}\in \{0,1\}$

$t_1$ and $t_2$ are integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can linearize it as follows:
$$
t_2-t_1\le M(2-x_{11}-x_{21})
$$
where $M$ is a large constant.

Indeed, if $x_{11}=x_{21}=1$, the right hand term equals $0$, therefore
$$
t_2\le t_1,
$$
Otherwise the constraint is equivalent to
$$
t_2\le t_1+M,
$$ 
which is always true provided $M$ is large enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very nice.